# Can an ELM327 adapter be used to flash a VIN?

Tags: bluetooth, electronic-control-module, elm-327, vin, flash-programing

Can a Bluetooth ELM327 adapter be used to flash a VIN?

It's claimed [here](https://ls1tech.com/forums/pcm-diagnostics-tuning/1885809-android-elm327-pcm-flash-app-ls-droid-read-only-released-22.html#post20149592) that

> The vin number is about the only thing in the PCM that's not a protected value.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is ... yes, you can. Don't go away so fast though ... there are caveats:

- The ELM327 device is only a passthrough. It is just a connection from your device to the PCM. There is no way (to my knowledge) to use just the ELM327 device for this.
- You have to have software to read, modify, and write the new VIN back into your PCM. Most often, the read/write software is different from the modifying software.
- This will not work on every vehicle. Some require specialized equipment.

The guy in [this video](https://youtu.be/ae-WWVEcCSI) briefly talks about using an ELM327. He uses other equipment to do it. You can see what he has to do to get the VIN changed on the GM PCM.

Comment: Interesting. There's probably some open-source software on [GitHub](https://github.com) that could be used.

Comment: I forgot I asked "[Open source software for automotive ECUs?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45363/24575)" on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com in 2017. It hasn't received any answers…

Comment: @Geremia - Something to remember which I didn't state is, you can most likely use the ELM327 for doing what you're suggesting, but the real question is: Should you? My suggestion is, not at all. Reason being is, the ELM327 has to be open to receive electronic interference. Because of this, if you should happen along any, you can brick your ECU, which means ... it's dead. Not much you can do but use it as a paperweight at that point.

Comment: I'm familiar with putting custom firmware on routers and bricking them. There's usually a way to restore the factory firmware.

Comment: @Geremia - When I say "brick", I mean brick. As in: no longer works.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with flashing VINs, but that wouldn't seem to require rewriting and flashing the firmware. I could be wrong.

Comment: @geremia - It seems it is [doable, but not fun](https://www.customecm.com/gm-bricked-pcm-recovery). Bottom line, any interruption in the flashing event can cause it to be bricked. Recovery is not easy, so why risk the biscuit in the first place. Removing all chances of bricking the PCM in the first place will make life a lot easier. Trying to flash a PCM through a Bluetooth connection would seem very risky to me. This would be a risk I personally would not want to take, especially if I was doing this on a customer's car.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141206/discussion-between-geremia-and-ps2).